# Print html table in 2 columns per page with fixed header

Tags: c#, html

i need to print some content in a way that it maximizes space and fills the whole page. For splitting content in 2 columns i do this on server side. I have a list and divide it in half. While this worked when i did it directly on the content coming from database, it does not work after i grouped countent by classes in order to not repeat information. Hence why everything looks uneven on the html page.

```
AbastecimentosColuna1 = referenciasList.Take(referenciasList.Count() / 2).ToList();
AbastecimentosColuna2 = referenciasList.Skip(referenciasList.Count() / 2).ToList();
```

In other words, how can keep content adjusted to whole page? Or is there any other way to split content in 2 columns without splitting the array from server side?

[image]

content

```
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 table-responsive">

    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered border-dark text-center">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Referência</th>
                        <th>Qtd. Abastecimento</th>
                        <th>Peças Por Caixa</th>
                        <th>Nº Caixas</th>
                        <th>Localização - Etiqueta FIFO</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.AbastecimentosColuna1)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Referencia)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QtdAbastecimento)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QtdPecasPorCaixa)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QtdCaixas)
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                @foreach (var localizacao in item.Localizacoes)
                                {
                                    <div class="row py-2">
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            @localizacao.Localizacao
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            @foreach (var etiqueta in localizacao.Etiquetas)
                                            {
                                                @etiqueta.Etiqueta
                                                <br />
                                            }
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                }

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-sm table-bordered border-dark text-center">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Referência</th>
                        <th>Qtd. Abastecimento</th>
                        <th>Peças Por Caixa</th>
                        <th>Nº Caixas</th>
                        <th>Localização - Etiqueta FIFO</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.AbastecimentosColuna2)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Referencia)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QtdAbastecimento)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QtdPecasPorCaixa)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QtdCaixas)
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                @foreach (var localizacao in item.Localizacoes)
                                {
                                    <div class="row py-2">
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            @localizacao.Localizacao
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            @foreach (var etiqueta in localizacao.Etiquetas)
                                            {
                                                @etiqueta.Etiqueta
                                                <br />
                                            }
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                }

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```